# Autocomplete suggestion a word delemited by @ in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have currently a chatbox, and I want when my users type @ , the autocompletion will be enabled.
But currently autocompletion working only with the first word , how I can enable autocompletion when users type @theword ?

For autocompletion :

```
$( "#chat_input" ).autocomplete({
  source: 'search.php'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the search method in `JQuery ui` autocomplete, the idea is to create your own regular expression and before returning anything you need to check if the first entered letter is equal to "**@**"

**See working example:**

```js
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];

$("#chat_input").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    var matcher = new RegExp(request.term.substring(1, request.term.length), "i");
    response($.grep(availableTags, function(item) {
      if (request.term[0] == "@") {
        return matcher.test(item);
      }
    }));
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="chat_input">Tags: </label>
  <input id="chat_input">
</div>
```